# How to create a Custom ScrollView that accepts SCNNodes

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, scenekit, scnnode

I'm using ARKit and SceneKit, I'm trying to make a scrollable wheel like the Price is Right wheel [here](https://gfycat.com/oddballfarflungbluefintuna) although it will be forward facing [like this](https://giphy.com/gifs/steven-yeun-chris-hardwick-josh-mcdermitt-3Bz64uK1A9uxO). When a number stops the user will be able to touch it and an action will take place. I added a gesture to sceneView to look for the sceneView hitTest to detect the node that was touched.

The wheel is made up of different individual nodes. UserA picks nodes from other users and UserB spins the wheel. It’s along those lines so the nodes will always have different values assigned to them. That’s why I need a scroll view.

I watched a ray wenderlich video on [youtube](https://youtu.be/tq52sfDjkI0) on how to make a custom scroll view  but the scroll view is a subclass of UIView and it doesn't accept SCNNodes.

I tried adding a collectionView to the SCNMaterial but it's the same problem as the scroll view because custom cell's won't let me import SceneKit to add nodes.

How can I create a scroll view for SceneKit that accepts SCNNodes?

Custom ScrollView for normal UIView's (this doesn't bounce it just scrolls):

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit

class CustomScrollView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panView(with:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    @objc fileprivate func panView(with gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let translation: CGPoint = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.20) {
            self.bounds.origin.y = self.bounds.origin.y - translation.y
        }
        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(.zero, in: self)
    }
}
```

SceneView Tap Gesture:

```
@objc func nodeWasTapped(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    guard let sceneView = recognizer.view as? ARSCNView else { return }

    let touchLocation: CGPoint = recognizer.location(in: sceneView)

    let hitResults = sceneView.hitTest(touchLocation, options: [:])
    if !hitResults.isEmpty {

        guard let hitResult = hitResults.first else { return }

        if let node = hitResult.node as? SCNNode {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use a scrollview? Don't you just want the 3D model to spin?

Comment: The individual node itself doesn’t spin, if it’s in a scrollview with other nodes the scroll view spins

Comment: I started working on creating my own and so far I'm up to step 4: 1. Create a parent node, 2. Inside the parent create an empty array that will hold child nodes 3. Create an instance of the parent and append the child nodes to the array 4. Enumerate through the array and position the children on top of each other 5. Add a swipe or pan gesture to the parent 6. When an up or down swipe is detected reposition the children 7. For the children that aren't in the parent's visible view to the user, set their opacity=0, 8. Add some bounce and acceleration/deceleration to the parent. That's all for now